# Change layout & appearance on 10.10

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-netbook, launcher

I recently upgraded to 10.10 from 10.04. I got the Netbook version. I like the new interface but it is a bit slower that the older version. Is there anyway to revert the current looks back to the another layout that does not consume as much resources? How do I change the layout so that I get rid of the launcher, bring back taskbar, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the default ubuntu interface by installing ubuntu-desktop and then choosing it on the login screen (you can change the "session" that you log in to).

To get the old netbook interface, I believe installing "ubuntu-netbook-efl" will give you the option, again in the "session" on the login screen. Make sure you install "ubuntu-netbook-efl-default-settings" to get it to look like 10.04, as well.